# ADD second URL to LIKE button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is it possible to put a link to a like button?

SO if you put a like button on a landing page, en someone hits this like button, he go's to another page?

hope someone can help me!

Mark

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for the edge.create event:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

It's fired whenever the user likes something.

Comment: I don't know how i edit that?
is there some way to get it in html done so i can put it on my website or iframe on Facebook?

Comment: How you subscribe to that event? Did you visit the link? The first example on that page is for "edge.create". It's not possible in HTML only. You have to use JavaScript. To redirect via Javascript you can use "location.href = 'https://example.com/my/path/myfile.html';".

Comment: the idea is..

Someone comes to my page (with is fan), and must like another page to see the downloadlink :( So i would post a like button in my page (which is a iframe) and after push the like button (the like the page) and they go trough a second page where the download links stands!

Comment: And? Where's the problem? I pretty much understand what you are trying to achieve and I told you the two tricky parts: You know now how to get notified when the user clicked on Like and you know how to redirect the user to another, second page using Javascript. What more do you need?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help Jan! I apprisiate that a lot! Let's make it very clear! I'm a dj and i have a Fan page. I use a special LANDINGTAB where people come on when they are visiting my page. When they like my page they see some exclusive content on the FANTAB. I made a track with another dj and i want to share this one on the FANTAB page. But, they can only download this one of they like the other dj's page. So i want that like button on the FAN TAB, and after they hit that like button, they go 2 a other page with downloadlink! Don't know which parts i must add or edit at like code

Comment: Okay, the problem: To really check if those people liked both Fanpages, you'd have to ask for their user_likes-permission, make a query for the two fanpages and then display the download-links or the appropriate like-buttons. Then you'd have to use the Javascript SDK and include the code from above (FB.Event.subscribe), updating the UI depending on the like-stati. If you have experience programming, that's easy. If not, you should start reading up about Javascript and the Facebook Javascript SDK.

Comment: That said: Maybe you should think about changing the promotion itself. Otherwise you'd have to think about cases where people already liked the other page etc.. For example: Include a soundcloud player on the tab, so the people see the two like-buttons while listening to the song instead of just downloading it and leaving. Make it possible to share the song. Link the Fanpages on all the pages you can listen to the song. If you are not technically able to force them, just make it easy for them. ;)

Comment: but it isn't possible that you give the like button an extra url that opens in a new window or something like that?

Comment: ... okay, one last try: No, the like button won't do anything but toggle if the user likes some OG-object (a fanpage, a website etc.). because that's what a like-button is for. if you want it to do anything else (e.g.: opening another page after a like), you'll have to implement that yourself. I don't understand why you think that there could be such a parameter.